# Django queryset get Avg() of 2 fields

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    list_price = models.IntegerField()
    sold_price = models.IntegerField()
```

I know that to get the average of say, the `sold_price`, I would do `Listing.objects.aggregate(Avg('sold_price'))`.

What I want to find is the average sale-to-list price.  Basically the average of the `sold_price` / `list_price`.  Something like:

`Listing.objects.aggregate(Avg('sold_price' / 'list_price'))`

Obviously the above statement doesn't work.  Is there some way to do this with Django ORM?

Comment: Try: `.aggregate(Avg(Value('sold_price' )/Value('list_price')))`

Comment: @Chiefir That pointed me in the right direction thanks.  After running into several errors, the following expression did the trick - `.aggregate(stl=Avg(F('sold_price' )/F('list_price'), output_field=IntegerField()))`

Comment: Yep, I was not sure what was better to use in that case: `F()` or `Value()` :)

Comment: Using `Value()` gave me this error - `Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.`.  Using `F()` solved the issue.  I had to add `stl=` to solve `TypeError: Complex aggregates require an alias`.  I also had to add `output_field` to solve `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field`.  Just writing this down in case anyone else comes across this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to aggregate the average of a calculation based on two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458958/how-to-aggregate-the-average-of-a-calculation-based-on-two-columns)