# How to aggregate the average of a calculation based on two columns?

Tags: python, django, average, django-orm

I want to write a Django query to give me the average across all rows in my table. My model looks like

```
class StatByDow(models.Model):
    total_score = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    num_articles = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    day_of_week = IntegerField(
        null=True,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(6),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ]
    )
```

and I attempt to calculate the average like this

```
everything_avg = StatByDow.objects.all().aggregate(Avg(Func(F('total_score') / F('num_articles'))))
```

but this results in the error

```
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainsite_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 362, in aggregate
    raise TypeError("Complex aggregates require an alias")
TypeError: Complex aggregates require an alias
```

What's the right way to calculate the average?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `Func` for the division, but you need to reconcile the two different field types. Use an [ExpressionWrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper) around `Avg`:

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper

everything_avg = (StatByDow.objects
    .aggregate(avg=ExpressionWrapper(
        Avg(F('total_score') / F('num_articles')),
        DecimalField()
    ))
)
```

You could also use a `Cast` from integer to decimal (not with PostgreSQL, which objects to Django's syntax `::numeric(NONE, NONE)`) or an `ExpressionWrapper` around the division, but just one `ExpressionWrapper` at the end is the quickest solution as it happens once at the end.

Comment: Thanks.  I added the Cast, but now I get the error, 'django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "none" LINE 1: ... ("mainpage_mainpagestatbydow"."num_articles")::numeric(No...'

Comment: PostgreSQL objects to Django's cast syntax `::numeric(NONE, NONE)`; just `::numeric` would work. You're left with the `ExpressionWrapper` then.

Comment: Just ran into the `::numeric(NONE, NONE)` issue with PG and after seeing these comments was about to ditch the fix I was working on. I did do some digging into the code and `Cast()` can be used with PG, one just needs to specify the `max_digits` and `decimal_places` kwargs if using `DecimalField`: `qs = qs.annotate(bar=Cast('foo', DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)))`

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a name of an alias (obviously by the error text) for aggregate function. the query should be something like this:

```
everything_avg = StatByDow.objects.all().aggregate(avg_f=Avg(Func(F('total_score') / F('num_articles'))))
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  That results in the error, "django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field"